# Сколько времени занимает присвоение знака? Как создаются знаки?

Tags: поддержка, faq

Подсчитываются ли баллы для присуждения знаков в реальном времени или это происходит в фоне? Сколько времени занимает процесс присуждения знака после того, как соответствующие требования к его получению будут выполнены?

Используются ли в Stack Overflow дополнительные сервисы, например, для поддержки системы знаков, почтовых рассылок о них или подсчета баллов для присуждения знаков?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод статьи «http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1716/274323».</sub>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Обычные знаки

Регулярная задача: для выполнения некоторых действий на сайте существует целый ряд регулярных задач, выполняемых через определенные интервалы времени (каждые несколько минут, каждый час, каждый день и т. д.). Для множества знаков подобные процедуры выполняются циклически с интервалом в несколько минут.

**Общее правило для знаков:** подождите хотя бы 24 часа. Если по прошествии этого времени знак не присвоен, вы, скорее всего, не соответствуете критериям, предъявляемым к обладателю этого знака. См. [список всех знаков с полными описаниями](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions).

---

### Знаки по метке

Вычисления знаков по меткам производятся ежедневно в 03:00 UTC (06:00 МСК). Именно в это время происходит обновление старых и присваивание новых знаков.

Аналогично если вы *не* получили знак к этому времени, вы, вероятно, не соответствуете каким–либо критериям. Чтобы узнать, соответствует ли ваша статистика требованиям на получение знака, проверьте свою репутацию. Также учтите, что для того, чтобы по метке присуждались знаки, она должна присутствовать не менее чем в 100 вопросах.